# IE9 - cursor disappearing or blinking very fast in text fields

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, internet-explorer-9

The typing cursor is disappearing or showing randomly in IE9 for a site I'm creating.

After some investigation, I found out that this is being caused by some scrolling banners at the bottom of the page. The cursor disappears completely in text box when on the screen the banners are showing, but when i scroll to hide the banners everything returns to normal.

I have set up a test fiddle to describe this: http://jsfiddle.net/uruwf/3/ After messing with the frameRate of the image scroller the cursor speed changes as well.

I tried already changing to a different jQuery image scroller and the issue persists. This is reproducible Only in IE9 (not even IE6).

There are too many forms on this site for it to be ignored.

Possible solutions/answers I'm seeking:

1 - Make the cursor display as it should and does in other browsers (ideal - blinking when waiting to type, no-blink when typing)

2 - Force the cursor to display always when on focus (no blink at all)

3 - Force the cursor to blink  always when on focus (constant blinking)

4 - Anything else that you can think of that would be user friendly

Your Help is VERY much appreciated!

Comment: From http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/: "Any feedback or bugs should be directed to @logicbox or will@logicbox.net. Enjoy!". Did you already try that?

Comment: Thanks, i'm still waiting for a response from them, unfortunatelly I tried 1 other jquery scroller (smoothdivscroll.com) and the issue is identical. Been struggling with this for 3 days now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this looks like it's an CPU/thread management issue, increasing the frame rate makes the cursor appearance more intermittent until it finally doesn't appear at all. Depending on CPU speed setting a lower frame rate might make the blinking work acceptably.

I did a google search and couldn't find any answers to this issue (apart from ones that suggested downgrading to IE8), amusingly the first result I looked at was this very question!

You could instead use a solution that animates the 'left' property, though this would result in lower performance across every browser.